# Intermittent nodejs container crashloop with "Cannot destructure property 'BaseClass' of undefined" from redis

Tags: node.js, redis, rancher, hapi, dynatrace

We have a Node.js monorepo application, where we build a Docker image and deploy a multi container (2 containers). Both containers share various packages from the monorepo but have different entry points located in separate folders/packages.

Lately, we've been experiencing intermittent container crash loops. The error message we encounter is "Cannot destructure property 'BaseClass' of undefined from Redis," which is a transitive dependency for the Hapi.js web server.

[Issue snipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFALG.png)

The issue seems to be resolved temporarily when we delete and recreate the pod. Additionally, when we manually kill the running process inside the container (e.g., using the command `kill 1`), it restarts successfully. However, sometimes the issue reoccurs, while other times it doesn't.

Unfortunately, we haven't been able to reproduce this issue consistently. We came across a suggestion in this link (https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/2405) that indicates it could be related to Dynatrace. However, without a reliable method to reproduce the issue, we can't confirm if Dynatrace is indeed the cause.

Here's the stack of technologies we're using:

1. Runtime: Node.js 14.21.3
2. Web server: Hapi.js 20.2.2
3. Containerization technology: Docker
4. Container orchestrator: Rancher

Could you please point me in the right direction.